# Glusterfs add a new server for replicated configuration

Tags: glusterfs

I have this volume:

```
$ gluster volume status 
Status of volume: staging
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick glfs2:/data/brick1/staging            49155     0          Y       13221

Task Status of Volume staging
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks
```

and:

```
$ gluster volume info
Volume Name: staging
Type: Distribute
Volume ID: 8c290a3f-3616-4c35-b641-6e7b7f79fa06

Status: Started
Number of Bricks: 1
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: glfs2:/data/brick1/staging
Options Reconfigured:
transport.address-family: inet6
performance.readdir-ahead: on
nfs.disable: on
```

I would like to add a new server to get a replicated 1x2=2 setup.

I did this:

```
$ gluster peer probe glfs1
peer probe: success. Host glfs1 port 24007 already in peer list
$ cd /data/brick1/
$ rsync -aAXHhv --delete --progress staging staging@glfs1:/data/brick1/ --exclude prod/.glusterfs/ --exclude prod/.trashcan/
```

And this:

```
$ gluster volume add-brick staging glfs1:/data/brick1/staging
volume add-brick: failed: Pre Validation failed on 2001:41d0:303:553::. /data/brick1/staging is already part of a volume
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following works:

```
$ gluster volume add-brick staging replica 2 glfs1:/data/brick1/staging force
```